# ASP.NET MVC How to invoke the other controller's action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

(Solved, look @ the end of this desctiption)

Hi, let's say that I have that URL:

```
http://mystite.com
```

then, I use the `HomeController` and the `Index` action.

but, if the URL looks like

```
http://mystite.com/itemID
```

`itemID` is a string, it is optional, then I use `MyController` and action `ViewContent`

the Global.asax file:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "ViewItemContent",
        "{itemID}",
        new { controller = "My", 
              action = "ViewContent", 
              itemID = UrlParameter.Optional 
            }
    );
```

the problem is, when I user the 1st URL the server treats it as 2nd URL (what's obvious). So, if the `itemID` parameter is `NULL` how then invoke the `HomeController`'s `Index` action from the `MyController`?

I tried

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

but it always redirects me back to the `MyController`'s `ViewContent` action

### SOLVED

I solved it by moving the RedirectToAction method from the `MyController`'s `ViewContent` action to the `HomeController`'s `Index` action.

I tried to redirect from the `MyController` -> `Home` and it didn't work.
Now I reversed the redirecting, from `Home` -> `MyController` by

```
return RedirectToAction("ViewCategory", "Category", new { itemID = itemID });
```

and in that case everything works :)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you not configure the route properly. Think and learn how the route works. It can be tricky if your route to the other route quite similar and how it can be fall back to the other route. The sequence is important.

Maybe you just put the `"ViewItemContent"` route above the other route. Your solution make another unnecessary round trip to the server because of `RedirectToAction`.

Actually you can put another route at the top:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Home",
    "",
    new { controller = "Home", 
          action = "Index"
        }
);
```

So MVC will look for this first and since `http://mystite.com` have nothing at the back, the "Home" route will take precedence and it will use `Home` controller with `Index` action directly.